# Translating of menu item creates new menu item

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

I have installed these modules concerning menu translation:

Entity Translation Menu - entity_translation_i18n_menu

Menu Translation - i18n_menu

For now, when I translate a menu item, a new  - translated menu item is created and I need to set weight and parent to this new item again.

How to achieve, that when I translate menu item, no new menu item is created? So I will just translate one string - the visible title?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for i18n system. In Drupal translating node creates new node, translating menu item creates new menu item and so on, that's the way it is designed and redesign+rewrite is not a task for Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that it is not possible, I just asked whether it is possible. The asnwer, that it is not possible now sis answer on my question, too. But still, with Entity translation module you can translate nodes without creating new ones, am I right?